# Show object as name value pair instead of instance variable

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to implement a gem that is redis wrapper for other library i.e to store the ruby object in the redis.

all work well but what I want is when I do

`[Class].all`
 It give object like this

`[#<Peagon:0x007fba589de3a0 @name="a", @omg=false ,@payload="one",@handler="--- one\n...\n"> ,#<Peagon:0x007fba589de1a0 @name="b", @omg=true,@payload="two",@handler="--- two\n...\n">]`

but instead I want it to be  look like how active record present the object

`[#<Peagon name: "a",omg: false ,handler: "--- one\n...\n"> ,#<Peagon name="b", omg: true,handler: "--- two\n...\n">]`

The reason for this that I not interested in showing the user the `@payload` instance variable because that is something set by the other library

so basically like this happen 
**[My gem]**

```
class Peagon
 include SomeModule
 attr_accessor :name,:omg,:handler 
 def initialize(options)
   @name = options[:name]
   @omg  = options
   self.payload_object = options[:payload_object]
 end

end
```

Now the **[Other Library]** has this `module` in it

```
module SomeModule 
 def payload=(object)
   @payload ||= object
   self.handler = @payload.to_yaml

 end 

 def payload
   @payload ||= YAML.load(self.handler)
 end
```

end

### NOTE :

Overwriting the payload method from other library is not in my mind

Now is it possible to get what I meant above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to adjust what `irb`, the Rails console, and friends will display for objects of your class. If so, they just call [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-inspect):

> **inspect → string**
>
> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of *obj*. By default, show the class name and the list of the instance variables and their values (by calling *inspect* on each of them). User defined classes should override this method to make better representation of *obj*.

So all you need to do is provide your own `inspect` implementation, something like:

```
def inspect
  "#<#{class} name: #{@name.inspect} ...>"
end
```

Comment: Opps I forget to mention I tried this approach too and I gave on this because the `inspect` return string object thereby making invoking of object/instance method impossible but in  activerecord it give you the object of the class so you can invoke the object/instance method on it

Comment: Any other approach that would give me back the object of the class with the desired behavior

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. When I say `Model` in the Rails console, I get `Model(id: integer, ...)` as a result because that's what `inspect` says for the class; if I say `Model.first`, I get `#<Model id: ...>` because that's what `inspect` says for the instance. None of this has anything to do with getting an "object of the class with the desired behavior".

Comment: Opps :P  I was thinking uptil now that inspect would return the string object cross checked it thanks